# read a value from another site

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
document.URL = "www.google.com";
var t = document.getElementById("xjsd").innerHTML; 
$('#r').html(t);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="r">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to read a value of a balise from another website ( for example google) and write it in my own page, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You think setting `document.URL` to another URL magically changes the document and allows you to access things in it? Huh? Don't guess-code!

Comment: You can't just grab data from random pages with JavaScript, it doesn't work that way.

Comment: you need to make a proxy with php and load the page there. Then you can parse through the rendered out page.

Comment: You need to use PHP (I see you tagged that). What exactly do you want to do? Maybe we can give you some hints.

Comment: http://christianheilmann.com/2010/01/10/loading-external-content-with-ajax-using-jquery-and-yql/

Comment: Or, you can use something like [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/).

Comment: You should create page to fetch data from other site with curl or file_get_content and then use ajax to fetch data from that page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. Otherwise it would be a major security risk (imagine my site accessing your online banking site where you are currently logged in).

However, you can use a server-side script that fetches the site and then returns the HTML code or even whatever information you are looking for.

Comment: how can i fetch the other site and return the value as html code

Comment: In PHP `file_get_contents()` is a simple way to do it as long as url_fopen_handlers are enabled.

Comment: how do you find the target balise if i use file_get_contents() ie how to fetch the balise in string